# Doctrine delete - update merge issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I do this with doctrine:

```
$ds = new Entity();
$ds->setId(4);
$ds->setField('Foo');
$em->merge($ds);
$em->flush();
```

And Doctrine executes an update.

But I do this:

```
$e = $em->find(1);
$r = $e->getRelatedCollection()->get(0);
$e->getRelatedCollection()->remove(0);
$e->getRelatedCollection()->remove(1);

$a = new TypeRelated();
$a->setId($r->getId());
$a->setField("bar");
$e->getRelatedCollection()->set(0, $a);
$a->setInverse($e);
$em->merge($e);
$em->flush();
```

And Doctrine executes two deletes, but no updates are executed. Why?

I tried some cases in that Doctrine tries to Insert a new field even when the detached entity has an Id.

Noticed that I'm using `orphanRemoval=true` in `$e` OneToMany relationship.

How can I do deletes and updates in the same flush?

My problem is that in the `PUT` operation I want to add, delete and modify related fields in the same operation. How can I do that?
I've tried lots of cases but I can't solve it.

Answer (score -1):

you can try persist insted of merge

$em->persist($e);